# Tomcat7w.exe Shutdown Mode

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration, shutdown

I am running Tomcat7 as a windows service. In the Tomcat7w.exe gui, there is a shutdown tab, and in that tab theere is a drop down box for the "Mode" option. The two options available are "JVM" or "Java". What are the differences between these two shutdown modes and what affect will each mode have? How will that affect the mode that I use for starting Tomcat7 as a windows service?